# Display off during Boot Manager OS selection on Surface Pro 7 with Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot

I've successfully installed two versions of Windows 10 in my Surface Pro 7 (Windows 10 and Windows 10 Insider Preview Build):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
flightsigning           Yes
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {4aa5e3d1-50b7-11ea-9e2b-c594e267064c}
displayorder            {current}
                        {3db0d6df-3e41-11ea-bd64-fe4246294ac9}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 60

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10 Insider Preview Build
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {52dc06bd-50f8-11ea-bb28-a1b76ce5d3f5}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
flightsigning           Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {4aa5e3d1-50b7-11ea-9e2b-c594e267064c}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {3db0d6df-3e41-11ea-bd64-fe4246294ac9}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {b7922fa3-05d9-11ea-bd91-ffd33e19a0f0}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=D:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {3db0d6de-3e41-11ea-bd64-fe4246294ac9}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

As far as I can tell, everything looks fine there. Now the problem is that when I boot the computer, the display is off during the Boot Manager OS selection (the blue screen where I am supposed to select the OS). The keyboard input works, so if I press DOWN + Enter I can boot up Windows 10 and if I press Enter I can boot up Windows 10 Insider Preview Build.

Any idea why the display is off during the Boot Manager OS selections screen?

Comment: @Moab Thanks for the suggestion. I can see the menu now, but weirdly enough, the keyboard (Surface Pro Type Cover) doesn't work immediately. Instead, I have to wait for like 5 seconds (or the second input?, not sure) for it to recognize my input. Anyway, this is better than not having boot menu at all, many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Ill make it an answer @Ruenzuo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this for all my W10 pc's. Try setting the legacy boot menu in W10, see if that solves it.

From an admin command prompt type (then hit enter):

> cmd>bcdedit /set "{current}" bootmenupolicy legacy

Answer (score 0):

Much appreciated for the workaround @Moab.

I've traced this to the Intel Iris Plus Graphics adapter. If the graphics adapter is disabled within Windows, or the drivers are not installed, the Standard boot manager is properly displayed. The driver that matters is the driver for the default entry in the boot manager.

I am going to open a case with Microsoft about this and hope the issue is fixed with new drivers or an update to the OS.